Error when using ee.Join.inner() to join two ImageCollections
I have two ImageCollections: Sentinel 1 and Sentinel 2. I managed to join them using ee.Join.inner() by applying a temporal filter, thus obtaining a new ImageCollection that combined the radar and optical bands into a single image. However, the bands are not in the bands structure, but in the features structure, which prevents me from performing geoprocessing operations or index operations between these bands.


My code
var poly = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
[[-54.78753991320279,-20.76018247385302],
[-54.44421715929654,-20.76018247385302],
[-54.44421715929654,-20.528863542361954],
[-54.78753991320279,-20.528863542361954],
[-54.78753991320279,-20.76018247385302]])

Map.addLayer(poly, {}, 'poly')
Map.centerObject(poly, 10)

// Load Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 Image Collections
var s1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filterBounds(poly)
.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
.select(['VV', 'VH'])
.map(function(image){
  return image.float()})
.map(function(img){
  return img.clip(poly)
});

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterBounds(poly)
.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'])
.map(function(image){
  return image.float()})
.map(function(img){
  return img.clip(poly)
});

var resample = function (image){
return image.resample('bilinear').reproject({
crs: s2.first().projection().crs(),
scale: 10})}


var s1r = s1.map(resample)
var s2r = s2.map(resample)

Map.addLayer(s1, {}, 's1r')
Map.addLayer(s2, {}, 's2r')

var days = 3
var timestamp = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)
var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
    'difference': timestamp,
    'leftField': 'system:time_start',
    'rightField': 'system:time_start'
})

// Aplicar junção para emparelhar coleções
var join = ee.Join.inner();
var paired = join.apply(s1r, s2r, maxDiffFilter);


// Adicionar as bandas da coleção secundária (Sentinel-2) à coleção primária (Sentinel-1)
var combined = paired.map(function(feature) {
  var primary = ee.Image(feature.get('primary')); // Imagem da coleção primária
  var secondary = ee.Image(feature.get('secondary')); // Imagem da coleção secundária
  
  return primary.addBands(secondary); // Adicionar bandas
});

// Verificar a coleção resultante
print(combined);

Map.addLayer(combined,null, 'combined')

I tried as shown in here, but doesn't work
var combined2 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(combined)
    
    print(combined2)


If you look at s1 and s2, you'll notice they don't have any bands either. To see which bands are in the collection, I normally get the bands from the first image in the collection: ee.ImageCollection(combined).first().bandNames()

thanks now I noticed that. in fact they are there. But why is it that when I use Map.addLayer(combined,null, 'combined') I can't access the bands (small gear) like in Map.addLayer(s1, {}, 's1r')

Reduce your image collection to an image before adding it to the map. With ‘s1.median()’ for instance.

I've used ee.Join.inner to join more than two Image Collections but using different Landsat products. In this case, bands are equivalent and it is only necessary to select and rename them adequately. In your case, Sentinel 1 and Sentinel 2 Image Collections have not equivalent bands and you need to use another approach for avoiding error messages. This approach involves dates and it can be adapted the code for this answer for pairing both images collections only for coincident dates.
In the following code snippet, COPERNICUS/S1_GRD 88 elements and COPERNICUS/S2 72 elements of your example are used to independently produce dates. These dates are compared for producing a list with 6,336 possibilities of -1, 0 and 1 values where 0 values correspond to perfect match.
var allDates_s1 = s1.aggregate_array('system:time_start');

var allDatesSimple_s1 = allDates_s1.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  });

print(allDatesSimple_s1);

var allDates_s2 = s2.aggregate_array('system:time_start');

var allDatesSimple_s2 = allDates_s2.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  });

print(allDatesSimple_s2);

var combinations = ee.List(
  allDatesSimple_s1.iterate(function (e1, acc) {
    var pairs = allDatesSimple_s2.map(function (e2) {
      return ee.String(e2).compareTo(ee.String(e1));
    });
    
    return ee.List(acc).cat(pairs);
    
  }, ee.List([]))
);

Following portion of code segregates coincident dates in both Image Collections.
var index = ee.List.sequence(0, combinations.length().subtract(1));

//print(index);

combinations = index.zip(combinations);

print("combinations", combinations);

var keyValues = combinations.map(function(ele) {

  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(ee.List(ele).get(1)).eq(0), 
                          ee.List(ele).get(0), 
                          -999);

});

keyValues = keyValues.removeAll([-999]);

print("indices in combinations2", keyValues);

var coincidentDates = keyValues.map(function(ele){
  
  return combinations2.get(ele);
  
});

print(coincidentDates);

Complete code can be acceded here and after running it results in following 17 coincident dates (as matrix to corroborate coincidences). Afterward, you can use these dates for filtering and to join the two Image Collections.
["2020-02-18","2020-02-18"]
["2020-02-23","2020-02-23"]
["2020-02-23","2020-02-23"]
["2020-04-18","2020-04-18"]
["2020-04-23","2020-04-23"]
["2020-04-23","2020-04-23"]
["2020-06-22","2020-06-22"]
["2020-06-22","2020-06-22"]
["2020-08-16","2020-08-16"]
["2020-08-21","2020-08-21"]
["2020-08-21","2020-08-21"]
["2020-10-15","2020-10-15"]
["2020-10-20","2020-10-20"]
["2020-10-20","2020-10-20"]
["2020-12-14","2020-12-14"]
["2020-12-19","2020-12-19"]
["2020-12-19","2020-12-19"] 

A picture with the result can be observed as follows:

